# Does Mark 14:12 indicate it being sunset?

Tags: john, contradiction, romans, mark, chronology

> “**On the first day of Unleavened Bread, when the Passover lamb was
> being sacrificed**, His disciples *said to Him, “Where do You want us to
> go and prepare for You to eat the Passover?”” ‭‭Mark‬ ‭14‬:‭12‬ ‭

**Q: Does Mark 14:12 start before sunset & the next day?**

**Q2: Did Jesus eat the Passover before the actual day of the Passover?**

Seems to be confusing:

> “**Now before the Feast of the Passover**, Jesus knowing that His hour had
> come that He would depart out of this world to the Father, having
> loved His own who were in the world, He loved them to the end. During
> supper, the devil having already put into the heart of Judas Iscariot,
> the son of Simon, to betray Him,
>
> So after receiving the morsel he went out immediately; **and it was
> night**.” ‭‭John‬ ‭13‬:‭1‬-‭2‬, ‭30‬

Answer (score 2):

The feast was prepared during the daytime of what we would call Thursday.  The first day of the feast of unleavened bread, otherwise called Passover, was Friday.

> And the first day of unleavened bread, when they killed the passover,
> his disciples said unto him, Where wilt thou that we go and prepare
> that thou mayest eat the passover? (Mark 14:12, KJV)

The Greek verb translated here in the KJV as "killed" (it could be translated as "sacrificed") is in the imperfect active indicative tense, which indicates a past action, and it can also indicate an ongoing action.  For example, if I speak of a past time in my life and say "I was eating vegetarian food" or "I ate vegetarian food," in English, both of these mean essentially the same thing: neither one requires that the action is happening *at that very moment,* merely that it is happening on an ongoing basis, as a habitual action.

So it is important not to overanalyze the translation to determine an exact time for when this occurred.  The text already gives us the time as "the first day of unleavened bread."  That is all we need to know.

The first day began at sunset.  It continued throughout the following day, ending at sunset on what we call Friday (the preparation day for the Sabbath).  It was during that day, Passover, that Jesus was crucified.  So he ate the Passover meal with his disciples in the evening of the day, and during the "morning" of the same day, which follows evening, Biblically (see Genesis 1), Jesus died.

In John, the text is clear that when Judas went out, it was dark (night).  That day would have started well before that when it was yet twilight--at sunset.  However, it was before sunset that the disciples gathered in that room and made preparations for the evening meal.

### Conclusion

Yes, Mark's account begins before sunset.  But it was after sunset that their Passover meal was to begin.

Comment: You mentioned: “The first day began at sunset. It continued throughout the following day, ending at sunset on what we call Friday (the preparation day for the Sabbath).” Why does John mention “preparation for the Passover” instead of “preparation of the sabbath”? If the Passover is a week long, does John’s usage make an issue?

Comment: @Cork88, the Passover was one day--leading into the first day of the feast of unleavened bread which lasted a week.  (See Lev. 23:5-8.). The feast of unleavened bread itself was bounded by two ceremonial sabbaths, comprising both the first day of that week and the last.  The Sabbath in which Jesus lay in the tomb was the first day of that week, and being both a ceremonial sabbath and the weekly Sabbath, became a "high Sabbath" (see John 19:31).  But when John speaks of "preparation" for the Passover, I think he is addressing the actual arrangements for the evening Passover meal.

Comment: Okay, granted, but then does that mean Jesus and His disciples ate the Passover on Thursday (which was the Passover?) Because Mark 14:12 seems to suggest the day in which He and His disciples ate is the same day He was crucified.

Comment: @Cork88 Yes, by modern reckoning, they ate the Passover on Thursday.  But by modern reckoning Jesus died on Friday.  Biblical reckoning began the day with the _evening_, starting at sunset, and the daytime was the second half of the day: "and the evening and the morning were the first day...etc." (see Genesis 1).  So in the Biblical reckoning, the fifth day (which we might call "Thursday") had already ended at sunset that day, and Thursday evening was the beginning of the sixth day, also called the preparation day for the Sabbath.

Answer (score 2):

The lamb is being slaughtered in afternoon of the 14th day in the first month, drained on blood and skinned then it's eaten at midnight and shall be eaten until the new day break forth. The first day of unleavened bread is the same day at even is the Passover it's the 14th to the 21st of the first month

> 6 and ye shall keep it up until **the fourteenth day of the same month:
> and the whole assembly of the congregation of Israel shall kill it in
> the evening**. **(Exodus 12:6 AKJV)**

> 17 And **ye shall observe the feast of unleavened bread**; for in this
> selfsame day have I brought your armies out of the land of Egypt:
> therefore shall ye observe this day in your generations by an
> ordinance for ever. 18 **In the first month, on the fourteenth day of
> the month at even, ye shall eat unleavened bread, until the one and
> twentieth day of the month** at even. **(Exodus 12:17-18 AKJV)**

Mark is talking of the day from a earlier point of view *“On the first day of Unleavened Bread, when the Passover lamb was being sacrificed, His disciples said to Him, “Where do You want us to go and prepare for You to eat the Passover?””* while John put the whole day together in Chapter 13 (**before** the Feast of the Passover - **During** supper - **after** receiving the morsel he went out immediately; and it was night.")

Comment: Doesn’t the Passover start at 15 Nisan?  I’m no expert.

Comment: @Cork88 I can't see that you have the Passover mentioned in Exodus 12:1-20, Leviticus 23:1-8. Many hold to the believe that the day start at even due to Genesis 1:5.